# How to count a division of a second, in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am calculating a timecode feature in my programme. For this I need hours, minutes, seconds and an extra value that ticks 24 times per second.

My hours, minutes, seconds are:

```
public void GetTime()
{
    Hours = float.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH"));
    Minutes = float.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm"));
    Seconds = float.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("ss"));
    Frames = ???
}
```

How can I calculate the frames value? (without using a timer, if possible)

Thank you.

Comment: `Hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;` no need in `ToString()`

Comment: Ditto for `Minutes` and `Seconds` - see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.second(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why don't you use `StopWatch` if you want to measure elapsed time?

Comment: I'd also do a single 'DateTime.Now` into a variable and get the components from that. Subsequent calls to `DateTime.Now` will return different values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: There's no indication that an elapsed time is what's wanted here - or if it is, the current code doesn't do the right thing *at all*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you just want [`DateTime.Millisecond`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond) and then perform some arithmetic.

However:

- You should only call `DateTime.Now` once, to avoid getting different values from different calls, leading to a very odd display
- There's no need to perform formatting and parsing
- There's no need to use non-integer types

Something like:

```
public void GetTime()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Hours = now.Hour;
    Minutes = now.Minute;
    Seconds = now.Second;
    Frames = (now.Millisecond * 24) / 1000;
}
```

Now that's the *computation* part. In order to update this regularly, you *will* need a timer or something similar. Also, due to the nature of system clocks - and timers - you shouldn't expect this code to give you a particularly *smooth* UI; it may feel a little jerky.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was after.